# Using JodaTime to compare time without date

Tags: time, jodatime

I'm trying to compare two times (in LocalTime format) in order to use them as part of an if statement.  I have done some research but all I can find it for using date without time, not the other way around.  I am trying to compare a time against the system time with the following code:

```
import org.joda.time.*;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;

LocalTime startTime2;
LocalTime airTime2;
LocalTime foamTime2;
LocalTime scTime22;


firstTime = airTime2;
secondTime = localTime;
return firstTime.compareTo(secondTime);
```

Which should return the larger value.  toLocalTime does not seem to be supported by JodaTime, does anyone know what the alternative would be?
  I had adapted the code from:

```
 LocalDate firstDate = date1.toLocalDate();
 LocalDate secondDate = date2.toLocalDate();
 return firstDate.compareTo(secondDate);
```

Comment: Assuming that you talk about the class `org.joda.time.DateTime` you can see that the method [toLocalTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#toLocalTime--) exists since version v1.3 which is stone old. And the class `LocalDateTime` has a similar method, too. Or do you speak about another class?

Comment: @MenoHochschild When using the toLocalTime method I get the error: "Cannot find symbol Symbol: method toLocalTime(), location variable airTime2 of type LocalTime.

Comment: The joda-class `org.joda.time.LocalTime` does not have a method `toLocalTime()`. It is already a `LocalTime` so no need for any conversion (to itself?). That is pretty clear if you look at the API. Please show a complete but short code example because you have left out a) the relevant import statements and b) the initialization code of your variables like `date1` or `airTime2`.

Comment: I've updated the code at the top.  I hadn't noticed that it was trying to convert to itself.  That simplifies the code somewhat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work pretty straightforward (JodaTime 2.9.1):

```
import org.joda.time.LocalTime;

LocalTime earlier = new LocalTime("23:00:00");
LocalTime later = new LocalTime("23:12:34");

System.out.println(earlier.compareTo(later));   // -1
System.out.println(later.compareTo(earlier));   // 1
System.out.println(earlier.compareTo(earlier)); // 0
```